# Wait for an AlwaysOn replica to be synchronized in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, powershell

I am working on a disaster recovery script. One part of it is not being consistent.

This is the code:

```
...
## Switch replica to Synchronous
Set-SqlAvailabilityReplica -AvailabilityMode "SynchronousCommit" `
-Path SQLSERVER:\Sql\Server1\Instance\AvailabilityGroups\SCOM-DBs\AvailabilityReplicas\Server2

## Wait until the replica is synchronized
$NewPrimary = Get-Item SQLSERVER:\Sql\Server1\Instance\AvailabilityGroups\AG-DBs\AvailabilityReplicas\Server2

Write-Host -NoNewline "Waiting for DBs to be synchronized"
while ($NewPrimary.RollupSynchronizationState -notlike 'Synchronized') {
   Write-Host  -NoNewline "."
   Start-Sleep -s 2
}
...
```

Sometimes gets synchronizing and it does not change even though SSMS dashboard changes. Is there a better in Powershell way to detect when the replica is synchronized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my problem.

I was working under the wrong assumption that the objects were automatically refreshed in Powershell. I added a "**$NewPrimary.Refresh()**" insinde of the while loop and that did the trick.

I hope this helps someone with the same wrong assumption in the future.

Comment: You can mark this as the answer since it solves the question.

Comment: Thanks @JohnM I know, but I have to wait until this answer is 24 hours old.